# form action =%s .What it mean? %s=server?

Tags: php, wordpress

When i am going through a code i see the code

```
<form name="registerform" action="%s" method="post">
  .... </form>
```

what is %s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your context, but `%s` is used in [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) to assign string. Example:

```
$myString = 'foo';
$output = sprintf('My string is %s!', $myString);
echo $output; // My string is foo!
```

In your case, it's possible that this is just some template and form action URL is assigned in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be the address (xyz.php) where you want to submit the form

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking what the `action` attribute does. I think they would like to know what `%s` *is*.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, it is an error. The `action` attribute holds a URL and a percent symbol in a URL must be followed by two hexadecimal digits

After error recovery, it has no special meaning. It is just the name of a resource to be requested from the server.

---

If that source code is template data (for example), rather than raw HTML, then it may have special meaning to whatever is processing it (in printf syntax, `%s` indicates a string).